# Overloading via Overriding

Tags: java

Why overloading is not happening here even though passing integer argument to method "p" . ?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B a = new A();
        a.p(10);
        a.p(10.0);
    }
}

class B {
    public void p(double i) {
        System.out.println(i * 2);
    }
}

class A extends B {
    // This method the method in B
    public void p( int i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    //added below code 
    public void p( double i) {
        System.out.println(i*5);
    }
}



Output:50.0
       50.0
```

Comment: It is incredibly confusing to make `A` extend `B`. Just about every example of overriding in the world makes `A` the parent class.

Answer (score 2):

Because the variable `a` is declared as `B`, only the `p` method declared in `B` is visible and thus chosen. There's no overriding involved.

When in doubt, annotate your method with `@Override` in your favorite IDE. The IDE won't let it compile if it's not actually overriding anything.

---

After your edit, you now have an overriden method in the form of `A#p(double)`. When you invoke

```
a.p(10);
a.p(10.0);
```

The method `p` visible on the `B` class will be invoked. Through polymorphism and because the variable `a` is of run time type `A`, the overriden method declared in `A` will be invoked.

---

Note that the `int` argument in

```
a.p(10);
```

becomes a `double` through [widening primitive conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).

Answer (score 0):

Because you're invoking things through a reference-to-a-`B`.  That only has one method.

Comment: Then what is the use of object A here? when the object(here "A") specific method executes?

Comment: @user3126466: In this case, there is no use.  There are no overridden methods in your example.

Comment: now i edited and added overriden method in Class A .So overloading is missing here..

Answer (score 0):

It's always calling the method in `B`, because:

- the variable is of type `B`, so the compiler only knows about the `double` method
- the method in `A` does not override `B`'s method because the parameter type `int` is different from `B`'s `double` - it's invisible to the calling code